# Preferred approach for multiple UITableViews

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

Which of these is the better solution for implementing multiple table views, and why?

1. Use a `UIViewController`, whose view contains several `UITableView`s, each with its own custom source.
2. Use a `UIViewController`, whose view contains several container views, each of which contains a `UITableViewController`.

Assume nothing complicated or exciting is going on.

Comment: You could also both point their source at the same viewcontroller and just have the delegate/datasource methods check the sender and route to your custom methods, assuming it doesn't turn into too much of a mess.

Comment: For code management, I think it would be easier to manage separate `UITableViewController`s, but that's just me.

Comment: What is the exact use case of this? Displaying several table views one below another?

Answer (score 0):

Having gone through this myself recently, I highly recommend one table view per viewcontroller, so to do your option 2. Otherwise, your single viewcontroller will be extremely monolithic and huge in code, and hard to read. Basically, every tableview data source and delegate method will have a if/else block to detect which table view is calling it, and respond accordingly. I originally did this and while it worked, the files were huge and I was having trouble just glancing at the code to see what it did. I refactored into separate view controllers, which was a much better design decision as it leads to much more readable code and you can isolate and discover dependencies.